# Highlight particular range in amchart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

Is there a way to highlight a particular range of the chart´s background between two times?

Here is an example what i want to recreate: [Example chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l218C.png) (actually this is my chart, i add the highlight area with photoshop to show you).

In the y-axis is temperature and x-axis is the date time.

This is the javascript:

```
var chartData = generateData();
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "marginRight": 80,
    "autoMarginOffset": 20,
    "marginTop": 7,
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "valueAxes": [{
        "axisAlpha": 0.2,
        "dashLength": 1,
        "position": "left"
    }],
    "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
    "graphs": [{
        "id": "g1",
        "balloonText": "[[value]]°",
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
        "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "hideBulletsCount": 50,
        "title": "red line",
        "valueField": "temperature",
        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
        "balloon": {
            "drop": true
        }
    }],
    "chartScrollbar": {
        //"graph": "g1",
        "oppositeAxis": false,
        "scrollbarHeight": 30,
        "dragIcon": "dragIconRectBig"
    },
    "chartCursor": {
        "limitToGraph": "g1",
        "categoryBalloonDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS"
    },
    "categoryField": "date",
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD HH:NN:SS",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "minPeriod": "hh",
        "parseDates": true,
        "axisColor": "#DADADA",
        "dashLength": 1,
        "minorGridEnabled": true
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": false
    }
});

chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);
zoomChart();

// this method is called when chart is first inited as we listen for "rendered" event
function zoomChart() {
    // different zoom methods can be used - zoomToIndexes, zoomToDates, zoomToCategoryValues
    chart.zoomToIndexes(chartData.length - 40, chartData.length - 1);
    //chart.zoomToDates(new Date(@Model.ElementAt(2).Timestamp * 1000), new Date());
}


function generateData() {
    var data = [];
    var date;
    var temp;
    @foreach (var wth in Model.OrderBy(e => e.Timestamp))
    {
        <text>
            debugger;
            temp = @wth.Temperature;
            date = new Date(@wth.Timestamp * 1000);

            data.push({
                date: date,
                temperature: temp
            });
    </text>
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`guides`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/Guide) to highlight a range by setting a start/end point and fill color, for example:

```
"categoryAxis": {
    // ...
    "guides": [{
      "date": "2013-01-01",
      "toDate": "2013-01-18",
      "fillAlpha": .5,
      "fillColor": "#00ff88"
    }]
}
```

Demo:

```js
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "marginRight": 40,
    "marginLeft": 40,
    "autoMarginOffset": 20,
    "mouseWheelZoomEnabled":true,
    "dataDateFormat": "YYYY-MM-DD",
    "valueAxes": [{
        "id": "v1",
        "axisAlpha": 0,
        "position": "left",
        "ignoreAxisWidth":true
    }],
    "balloon": {
        "borderThickness": 1,
        "shadowAlpha": 0
    },
    "graphs": [{
        "id": "g1",
        "balloon":{
          "drop":true,
          "adjustBorderColor":false,
          "color":"#ffffff"
        },
        "bullet": "round",
        "bulletBorderAlpha": 1,
        "bulletColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "bulletSize": 5,
        "hideBulletsCount": 50,
        "lineThickness": 2,
        "title": "red line",
        "useLineColorForBulletBorder": true,
        "valueField": "value",
        "balloonText": "<span style='font-size:18px;'>[[value]]</span>"
    }],
    "chartScrollbar": {
        "graph": "g1",
        "oppositeAxis":false,
        "offset":30,
        "scrollbarHeight": 80,
        "backgroundAlpha": 0,
        "selectedBackgroundAlpha": 0.1,
        "selectedBackgroundColor": "#888888",
        "graphFillAlpha": 0,
        "graphLineAlpha": 0.5,
        "selectedGraphFillAlpha": 0,
        "selectedGraphLineAlpha": 1,
        "autoGridCount":true,
        "color":"#AAAAAA"
    },
    "chartCursor": {
        "pan": true,
        "valueLineEnabled": true,
        "valueLineBalloonEnabled": true,
        "cursorAlpha":1,
        "cursorColor":"#258cbb",
        "limitToGraph":"g1",
        "valueLineAlpha":0.2,
        "valueZoomable":true
    },
    "valueScrollbar":{
      "oppositeAxis":false,
      "offset":50,
      "scrollbarHeight":10
    },
    "categoryField": "date",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
        "dashLength": 1,
        "minorGridEnabled": true,
        "guides": [{
         "date": "2013-01-01",
          "toDate": "2013-01-18",
          "fillAlpha": .5,
          "fillColor": "#00ff88"
        }]
    },
    "export": {
        "enabled": true
    },
    "dataProvider": [{
        "date": "2012-07-27",
        "value": 13
    }, {
        "date": "2012-07-28",
        "value": 11
    }, {
        "date": "2012-07-29",
        "value": 15
    }, {
        "date": "2012-07-30",
        "value": 16
    }, {
        "date": "2012-07-31",
        "value": 18
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-01",
        "value": 13
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-02",
        "value": 22
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-03",
        "value": 23
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-04",
        "value": 20
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-05",
        "value": 17
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-06",
        "value": 16
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-07",
        "value": 18
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-08",
        "value": 21
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-09",
        "value": 26
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-10",
        "value": 24
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-11",
        "value": 29
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-12",
        "value": 32
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-13",
        "value": 18
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-14",
        "value": 24
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-15",
        "value": 22
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-16",
        "value": 18
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-17",
        "value": 19
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-18",
        "value": 14
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-19",
        "value": 15
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-20",
        "value": 12
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-21",
        "value": 8
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-22",
        "value": 9
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-23",
        "value": 8
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-24",
        "value": 7
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-25",
        "value": 5
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-26",
        "value": 11
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-27",
        "value": 13
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-28",
        "value": 18
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-29",
        "value": 20
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-30",
        "value": 29
    }, {
        "date": "2012-08-31",
        "value": 33
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-01",
        "value": 42
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-02",
        "value": 35
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-03",
        "value": 31
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-04",
        "value": 47
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-05",
        "value": 52
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-06",
        "value": 46
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-07",
        "value": 41
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-08",
        "value": 43
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-09",
        "value": 40
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-10",
        "value": 39
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-11",
        "value": 34
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-12",
        "value": 29
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-13",
        "value": 34
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-14",
        "value": 37
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-15",
        "value": 42
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-16",
        "value": 49
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-17",
        "value": 46
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-18",
        "value": 47
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-19",
        "value": 55
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-20",
        "value": 59
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-21",
        "value": 58
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-22",
        "value": 57
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-23",
        "value": 61
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-24",
        "value": 59
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-25",
        "value": 67
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-26",
        "value": 65
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-27",
        "value": 61
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-28",
        "value": 66
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-29",
        "value": 69
    }, {
        "date": "2012-09-30",
        "value": 71
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-01",
        "value": 67
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-02",
        "value": 63
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-03",
        "value": 46
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-04",
        "value": 32
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-05",
        "value": 21
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-06",
        "value": 18
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-07",
        "value": 21
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-08",
        "value": 28
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-09",
        "value": 27
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-10",
        "value": 36
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-11",
        "value": 33
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-12",
        "value": 31
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-13",
        "value": 30
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-14",
        "value": 34
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-15",
        "value": 38
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-16",
        "value": 37
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-17",
        "value": 44
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-18",
        "value": 49
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-19",
        "value": 53
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-20",
        "value": 57
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-21",
        "value": 60
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-22",
        "value": 61
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-23",
        "value": 69
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-24",
        "value": 67
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-25",
        "value": 72
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-26",
        "value": 77
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-27",
        "value": 75
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-28",
        "value": 70
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-29",
        "value": 72
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-30",
        "value": 70
    }, {
        "date": "2012-10-31",
        "value": 72
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-01",
        "value": 73
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-02",
        "value": 67
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-03",
        "value": 68
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-04",
        "value": 65
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-05",
        "value": 71
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-06",
        "value": 75
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-07",
        "value": 74
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-08",
        "value": 71
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-09",
        "value": 76
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-10",
        "value": 77
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-11",
        "value": 81
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-12",
        "value": 83
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-13",
        "value": 80
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-14",
        "value": 81
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-15",
        "value": 87
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-16",
        "value": 82
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-17",
        "value": 86
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-18",
        "value": 80
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-19",
        "value": 87
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-20",
        "value": 83
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-21",
        "value": 85
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-22",
        "value": 84
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-23",
        "value": 82
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-24",
        "value": 73
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-25",
        "value": 71
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-26",
        "value": 75
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-27",
        "value": 79
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-28",
        "value": 70
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-29",
        "value": 73
    }, {
        "date": "2012-11-30",
        "value": 61
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-01",
        "value": 62
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-02",
        "value": 66
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-03",
        "value": 65
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-04",
        "value": 73
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-05",
        "value": 79
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-06",
        "value": 78
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-07",
        "value": 78
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-08",
        "value": 78
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-09",
        "value": 74
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-10",
        "value": 73
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-11",
        "value": 75
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-12",
        "value": 70
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-13",
        "value": 77
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-14",
        "value": 67
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-15",
        "value": 62
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-16",
        "value": 64
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-17",
        "value": 61
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-18",
        "value": 59
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-19",
        "value": 53
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-20",
        "value": 54
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-21",
        "value": 56
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-22",
        "value": 59
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-23",
        "value": 58
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-24",
        "value": 55
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-25",
        "value": 52
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-26",
        "value": 54
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-27",
        "value": 50
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-28",
        "value": 50
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-29",
        "value": 51
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-30",
        "value": 52
    }, {
        "date": "2012-12-31",
        "value": 58
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-01",
        "value": 60
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-02",
        "value": 67
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-03",
        "value": 64
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-04",
        "value": 66
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-05",
        "value": 60
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-06",
        "value": 63
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-07",
        "value": 61
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-08",
        "value": 60
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-09",
        "value": 65
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-10",
        "value": 75
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-11",
        "value": 77
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-12",
        "value": 78
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-13",
        "value": 70
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-14",
        "value": 70
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-15",
        "value": 73
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-16",
        "value": 71
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-17",
        "value": 74
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-18",
        "value": 78
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-19",
        "value": 85
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-20",
        "value": 82
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-21",
        "value": 83
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-22",
        "value": 88
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-23",
        "value": 85
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-24",
        "value": 85
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-25",
        "value": 80
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-26",
        "value": 87
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-27",
        "value": 84
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-28",
        "value": 83
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-29",
        "value": 84
    }, {
        "date": "2013-01-30",
        "value": 81
    }]
});

chart.addListener("rendered", zoomChart);

zoomChart();

function zoomChart() {
    chart.zoomToIndexes(chart.dataProvider.length - 40, chart.dataProvider.length - 1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Comment: Awesome!!, thanks @xorspark, I've been searching for hours. i love you!! =D